# What is the simplest way to round floats correctly in Python?

Tags: python, rounding

As many of you know already, sometimes Python rounds for instance 3.75.... to 3.7 rather than 3.8, which is of course a problem. (I'm on Python 3.)

Another user presented as a solution here a very nice function in Python that he called round_exact (you can find this in Stack Overflow by searching), but unfortunately even this function is suboptimal for my purposes, as it seems to consider a zero in the last decimal place always redundant and cuts it away.

(I mean, i would like to see 1.695 to be 1.70, if I wanted two decimals, rather than 1.7.)

So, I would still like to ask for additional opinions on how to deal with Python's shortcomings in rounding floats.

Comment: A zero in the last decimal place *is* redundant. You're looking for ways to print a number out, not round it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round - has a brief explanation of the behavior and a link. (BTW, this is not a "Python issue" but one related to IEEE 754 and relative precision floats with a base2 encoding.)

Comment: *"sometimes Python rounds for instance 3.75.... to 3.7 rather than 3.8"* - I just tested it and it rounds to 3.8. What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: @StefanPochmann - Sometimes it will actually do something like that, e.g. `round(2.675, 2)` produces `2.67`. See [the note in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I know, but that's a different issue... 3.75, unlike 2.675, is easily represented exactly. I also know about for example `round(4.5, 0)` giving `4.0`. But the claim was for 3.75, where I doubt it. So I'd like to know what their actual problem is.

Comment: Yep - the banker's rounding works fine; it's the floating-point math that causes that particular issue.

Comment: Thank you indeed for all the comments. I've done my homework now. "Round to nearest, ties away from zero" is what I want. (See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero) Banker's rounding is what I'm trying to avoid by all costs. And yes, I agree that a zero in the last decimal place is redundant... however, for instance in academia, you often want that last zero for the sake of consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decimal module allows precise control over rounding and it can retain trailing zeros:

```
>>> Decimal('1.695').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('1.70')
```

Comment: This seems to work 100% perfectly. I can't thank you enough. However, I noticed that ROUND_UP is not the right rounding option for me. By changing that to ROUND_HALF_UP seems to give me the "Round to nearest, ties away from zero" behavior that I'm looking for. (See also: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero)

Answer (score 1):

For a numerical display, you should look to print two decimals instead of one.  That can be accomplished with a specialized formatted print statement.

```
"{:.2f}".format(7.1) # prints 7.10
```

If you're concerned about there being decimal imprecision, look into the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module.  It provides up to 28 digits of accuracy and can be used to reliably print out those numbers as well.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed the decimal module that solved my problem, thanks for the tip.